# Need Help with Bathroom Exhaust Fan/Vent

Tags: bathroom, exhaust-fan, moisture

I have a bathroom exhaust fan that is not working. It seems to be a light/fan combo unit (see below pictures). The fan use to turn on when the light was turned on, but it's no longer functioning. The light works fine and I checked the wiring behind the wall switch and everything looks ok. I'm also confused because, when I take the fan grill off, I can't even see the fan itself. Please see the attached pictures.

- Does anyone know how to fix this? If not, Is anyone familiar with this unit?

Thank you in advance for any help!!!!
Backstory: This is in my apartment, which is why the vent has a fire damper, and the landlord/manager is a silver spoon rich kid who won't respond to my maintenance requests

[image: Light/Fan Combo Unit]

[image: With Vent Grill Removed]

Answer (score 2):

The fan may be an inline unit. This could be complicated and in a rental unit any maintenance should be done by professionals.

Document the requests for repair. State exactly the issue, ( The fan does not function.)   Add the dates this has been occuring.  ( not "for 2 weeks"  State " starting on January 30th and continuing currently."  Remind the reader that not having a fan prevents the humidity from being removed from the bathroom and can cause further issues, which will be outside of your control.
State that if the issue is not repaired in a timely manner,( 30 days.) you will be forced to have it repaired on your own and the cost will be deducted from the next rent payment.

Send the request for repair in an email and actual hard copy snail mail as well.   ( keep a copy for your records)

This will get the landlords attention. Should he then choose to ignore the issue, have it repaired and deduct the cost.  THAT will get his attention.

It will be a bonus if you can have a video of the fan not working, just in case you end up in court. You will have the benefit of an abundance of proof.

Comment: If you do not have a window in the bathroom that can be opened for ventilation to the outside then code **requires** ventilation to the outside https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IPMC2015/chapter-4-light-ventilation-and-occupancy-limitations#IPMC2015_Ch04_Sec403.2 Telling the landlord that code requires it may be much more useful than "good idea to prevent mold".

Comment: Thanks, both are good advice.